# Cardinal Commerce org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk Error while publishing Flutter app to Play Console

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-play-console

I am trying to publish my flutter app in Play Console but the Play Console has rejected the release bundle with the following error:

```
SPLIT_BUNDLE 2: :
SDK: Cardinal Commerce org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk (consider upgrading to version 2.2.7-2)
```

I have not directly implemented Cardinal Commerce library in my app in pubspec.yaml . Neither I have any implementation of it in my build.gradle file

After some research, I found that this sdk is used for payments and I also found an article that says this error occurs because of Braintree Payment SDK [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/202809778/app-rejected-cardinal-commerce-sdk-which-collects-but-may-not-be-limited-to-android-id-and-hardware?hl=en-GB)

So, I removed the `flutter_braintree` dependency and uploaded a new release still the app was rejected with the same error.
Here is list of dependencies in my
pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  dio: ^4.0.6
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # flutter_braintree: ^3.0.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  flutter_html: null
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.7
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  # flutter_stripe: ^7.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  flutterwave_standard: ^1.0.4
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  get: ^4.6.5
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.2
  http: ^0.13.5
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.1
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  location: ^4.4.0
  mercadopago_sdk: ^1.3.0
  paginate_firestore: ^1.0.3+1
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  paytm_allinonesdk: ^1.1.7
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  text_scroll: ^0.1.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  video_compress: ^3.1.2
  video_player: ^2.4.9
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.1
  connectivity_plus: ^4.0.2
  slide_to_act: ^2.0.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0
```

How should I solve the error now? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should run following commands in given order to resolve the issue

• `flutter clean`

• `flutter pub get`

• `flutter pub upgrade`

• `flutter build appbundle --release`